# How to update a queryset to include User's full name

Tags: python, django

Currently in my project I use the following code to obtain a list of Users:

```
all_manager = User.objects.filter(id__in=manager_list).values(
    "id", "first_name", "last_name"
)
```

For the User model there is no field called 'full_name' or something similar.

[I read the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/) and there is a method `get_full_name()`

The question is: How can I modify the queryset to include a 'full_name' key with its value?

Dummy Queryset:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'first_name': 'Steve', 'last_name': 'Jobs'}, {'id': 3, 'first_name': 'Tim', 'last_name': 'Cook'}]>
```

Desired Queryset:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'first_name': 'Steve', 'last_name': 'Jobs', 'full_name': 'Steve Jobs'}, {'id': 3, 'first_name': 'Tim', 'last_name': 'Cook', 'full_name': 'Tim Cook'}]>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use annotate. Just make sure you read up on the order (i.e. use annotate then values)

```py
from django.db.models import CharField, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

User.objects.annotate(
    full_name=Concat("first_name", Value(" "), "last_name", output_field=CharField())
).filter(id__in=manager_list).values("id", "first_name", "last_name", "full_name")
```

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#concat

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses

Comment: Note that full name calculation is a bit more complex than this (there should be a space between names and should take `name_order_convention` into account) but the idea is right.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect that @Selcuk ! but I'm a fan of just a single field called name tbh. It's more internationally compatible since not all languages (like Chinese) has this kinda format.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @acw! Sounds good but...how can I apply the filter `id__in=manager_list` using annotate?  Could you give an illustrative example using my provided code?

Comment: Sorry I missed that @Cheknov You can still use `.filter(id__in=manager_list)` anywhere

Comment: Also there is no Value function, I checked the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/

Comment: Ah apologies. Import it from `django.db.models`

Comment: Thank you so much! Before accepting the answer, `values` should be: `values("id", "first_name", "last_name", "full_name")`.  Could you edit your answer pls?

Then it works as expected!

Comment: Will definitely edit. Thanks for the patience too!